# how to get the url in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, event-handling

i have 2 pages, `index.html` and `about.html`

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    ... load jquery and jquery mobile...
</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
    ...content goes here...
        <a href="about.html?id=1"  data-role="button">about</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `about.html` has just the page data-role

```
<div data-role="page" id="about">
...content goes here...
</div>
```

the problem is that when i click on the link to go to the `about` page and i try to get the url string, well, it shows me `index.html`

```
window.location.toString();
```

or

```
$.mobile.activePage.data('url');
```

both return `index.html` instead of `about.html?id=1`

i understand that the `about.html` gets loaded into the index page, but how to grab that id??

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I don't know about phonegap, but you can do it with DOM. Get all child nodes of "index-id" element, and then get the href-attribute and split it from '?' to get the id. It seems obscure, but it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ChangePage`** method needs to be used to send parameters from one page to another:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index' ,function () {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

If you want to find out more take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to make it transparent it is my personal blog. Or it can be find [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600). Look for a  chapter called: **Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions**

Comment: your idea seems to work, i was trying to keep is simple, but this should be fine.